# CSS3 transform for text rotation in the context of a bar graph

Tags: css

I know there are many questions about rotating text via CSS here, and I've tried to apply their solutions to my situation, but I've been unable to get my situation working.

My goal is to create a bar graph, but in some cases data points are missing.  The designer would like an effect where the text, rotated 90 degree counter-clockwise, forms a column in place of the missing bar.

HTML:

```
        <li><div class="bar-missing">Results upcoming</div>
            <span>Aug &rsquo;15</span></li>
```

CSS:

```
      .trend-graph #bars li .bar-missing {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-align: center;
        color: #00AEEF;
        /* Safari */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        /* Firefox */
        -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        /* IE */
        -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        /* Opera */
        -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        /* Internet Explorer */
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3); 
}
```

With this code the "column" of text wraps into two lines, is positioned a bit too far to the right (should be centered above the x-axis label), and is far too high above the x-axis, as you can see in this example:

https://jsfiddle.net/wvfy6zje/

If I change the width of `div.bar-missing`, the text is on one line, but the container `li` gets super wide.  Putting a class on the container `li` to try to constrain the child `div.bar-missing` didn't make things much better.  Reading similar questions here on Stack Overflow made me despair of getting any solution involving heights and widths working properly, so I also tried using absolute positioning and negative margins to move things around without much success, either.

Comment: Add another standard `transform: rotate(-90deg);` to your CSS…

Comment: Added, but the problem persists.  Thanks, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this? https://jsfiddle.net/wvfy6zje/11/

I've basically copied the layout from your `li.bar` to  your `li.bar-blank` and added `white-space:nowrap` to prevent word wrapping:

```
.trend-graph #amh-bars li .bar-blank {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: #00AEEF;
    white-space: nowrap; /* ADDED */
    width: 27px;         /* ADDED */
    margin-left: 15px;   /* ADDED */
    position:absolute;   /* ADDED */
    bottom:10px;         /* ADDED */
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

Comment: Wow, nowrap would've never occurred to me in this situation.  Thanks so much!  If I may ask a follow-up -- the designer's mockup has the text centered vertically in the column (as opposed to aligned at the bottom).  I've played around with your solution a bit to see if I can get that effect, but I'm back in the same muddle as before.  Do you have any ideas here as well?  Thanks again!